# Determining a matrix from its definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $u$ is a $n \times 1$ matrix such that $u^Tu=1$. Determine the matrix $A=I-2uu^T$.

I have taken some specific examples and the answer is always $-I$. Is this true in general?

Comment: How about $u=e_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly not. Take $n=2$ and take $u=[\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\frac{\sqrt2}{2}]^T$.

Then, $uu^T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A\neq -I$.

---

You must have made a mistake in your calculation, because in actual fact, $A$ can *NEVER* be equal to $-I$ if $n\geq 2$. This is because if $A=-I$, that means that, from $A=I-2uu^T$, you get $$2uu^T = 2I,$$ meaning that $uu^T = I$.

This is impossible, since $uu^T$ has rank $1$, while $I$ has rank $n$.

Comment: Nice explanation. This shows $uu^T = I$ and $u^Tu = 1$ is possible only for $n=1$ and $u=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

What specific examples did you take? The dumbest one is
$$u = (1,0, \dots, 0)^T$$ and
$$I-2uu^T = \left( \begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \dots &0 \\
&& \ddots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots &1
\end{matrix} \right) \ne -I$$

EDIT: this holds whenever the characteristic of the field is $\neq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true,  $uu^T$ will have rank 1 regardless of what $n\geq1$ you choose. Therefore you have a matrix minus a number and thus you will never end up with $-I$ but rather with $A=I-2$ with $A$ and $I$ being $n \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

As the given 
$$u^Tu=1$$
Take $u^T$ is the inverse of $u$. And so
$$u^Tu=I$$
and also
$$uu^T=I$$
Now as
$$A=I-2uu^T$$
$$A=I-2I$$
$$A=-I$$
It is only true if $u^T$ is inverse of $u$.

Now
$$u^T_{1 \times n}.u_{n \times 1} = I_{1 \times 1}$$
and 
$$u_{n \times 1}.u^T_{1 \times n} = I_{n \times n}$$
and 
$$I_{1 \times 1} = I_{n \times n}$$
Because determinant of both the matrix is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues of $uu^t$ are nothing but {${u^tu,0,0,..,0}$}. So, Eigenvalues of $A=I-2uu^t$ are$ {-1,1,1,...,1} $ which implies that $A \not= -I$ for any $n>=2$